# Cache issue with dynamic parameter in config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, caching, configuration

I have a multisite aplication with a log system depends on each site and I want that each of them has its own log file so I did that :

1) I use a dynamic variable in `config.yml` with depends on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: param.php }

    ...

monolog:
    handlers:
        user:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%domain_name%.%log_filename%
            channels: [user]
```

=> `%domain_name%` is my dynamic variable

2) I set it in app/config/param.php:

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$domain = preg_replace('/^www./', '', $url);

$container->setParameter('domain_name', $domain); // this set my variable `%domain_name%` with the current domain (ex: site1.com)
```

**Problem :**

This code works fine but when I switch to an other site, the value of %domain_name% remains equal to its initial value.

**Exemple :**

- I am in www.site1.com => `%domain_name%` value is "site1.com" so it works
  fine
- I switch to www.site2.com => `%domain_name%` value is always "site1.com" and
  not "site2.com"

**Why ?**

Cache issue. Indeed, Symfony load in cache `config.yml` so it keeps the first value of `%domain_name%`

To delete this value I have to execute this command:  `rm -rf app/cache/*` but it is not a solution.

So nobody has a solution for this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem in our multi-site CMS environment. Symfony is primarily designed to run a **single** site, so the config.yml gets run once, and then cached. That means if you inject dynamic parameters into the config.yml (by any means: Globals, Constants, Apache Environment, etc), after the first run they are cached for each subsequent request :( So the next unique domain site request, will be using the cached values from the first site. In most cases, this creates problems.

Some people have suggested creating different **environments** for each site. But that's not practical when you host hundreds, thousands or millions of sites.

Alternative Cache Location
At the moment, the best solution we can conceive is to [specify a different cache folder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html) for each site. So you extend the `app/appKernel.php` and customize the `getCacheDir` function.

```
//app/appKernel.php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment.'/'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }
}
```

See [API Reference for Kernel](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, if you are using the parameter file/configuration as intended.

For me there is information missing, to answer your question directly, so here are the two possible scenarios:

**1) Site www.site1.com and www.site2.com is pointing at the SAME source (same server):**

In this case I wouldn't define the domain_name as an configuration value, course it is not an distinct configuration parameter it is more like a variable. Build a service or think about defining an additional environment.

**2) www.site1.com and www.site2.com are two distinct projects:**

In that case you shouldn't deploy the contents of the cache directory (which you should do anyway; but in this case it would be the issue ;)).

**EDIT**
You could implement different configuration files to solve:

- config_site1.yml # Configuration for www.site1.com
- config_site2.yml # Configuration for www.site2.com

Controller in your /web directory:

- app_site1.php
- app_site2.php

initialize the AppKernel with the requested environment, and point to the controller in your vhost config or your htaccess file.
I think you could change the app.php controller even to something like:

```
[...]
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$kernel = new AppKernel($request->giveMeMyHostEnvironmentMappingShizzle(), false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
[...]
```

kind regards

Comment: I am in the first case but I use monolog to write logs so I have to define path to log file in config.yml and I want that each site has its own log file so I use this dynamic variable

Comment: Yes ok, that makes sense.
Take a Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516301/symfony2-how-can-i-use-different-parameters-ini-per-host-name

They are using symfony2.0 as it looks like, but this could fix your issue. It's like suggested: Defining an additional Environment could/should be the best solution to your Problem.